# Incorrect file permissions for LAMP

Tags: apache, file-access

I have installed Apache 2.4.6 on my server and have the following virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName foobar1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/john/foobar1/foobar1.com
    <Directory /home/john/foobar1/foobar1.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require local
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /home/john/foobar1/logfiles/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /home/john/foobar1/logfiles/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I try and view http://foobar1.com (I have added 127.0.0.1 foobar1.com to my hosts file) I get the following error: `[core:error] [pid 23238] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:49853] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/john/foobar1/foobar1.com') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`

The file belong to user "john" and are in the group "john" too.  The permissions I used are: 
chmod -R go-rwx (for the document root)
chmod -R g+rw (for the document root)
chmod -R o+r (for the document root)

I can only view my site when I set the file permissions to 777... something I know is a major security weakness.  Why can I only view my site with the 777 setting?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server configurations.

Comment: actually it has got nothing to do with server configurations.  It however has everything to do with file permissions... something I believe is directly linked to secuirty

Comment: While file permissions are linked to security, questions about helping you setup certain permissions on your server is outside the scope of this site. I apologize for my friend down there who posted the answer, therefore confusing you into thinking that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Apache daemon is not running as user `john`. The Apache daemon, at least on RHEL/Fedora systems are running as the user `apache`.

To actually read files in your `DocumentRoot` directory, the directory permissions of `DocumentRoot` needs to be `drwxr-xr-x.`.

Also, be warned that if your server has Selinux enabled, your `DocumentRoot` directory most likely has the wrong Selinux context which will block Apache's access to the directory. It is good practice to keep all your `DocumentRoot` directories under `/var/www` (for RHEL based distros, other distros might have different web roots). An alternative will be to change the Selinux context of the `DocumentRoot` directory with `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/john/foobar1/foobar1.com`.

Comment: Sorry I should have included this too.  I added the  user `john` to the apache group (www-root on my Ubuntu set-up).  So if I run the command "groups www-data" I get the output: "www-data : www-data john".  I also added this the other way around so if I run the command "groups john" I get "john : john sudo www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare"
I thought that with Apache being part of John's group it could do all the things "john" could do.

Comment: @JohnCrawford Firstly, that's a horrible idea. You should never add any old user accounts to the apache group. Secondly, you have a completely wrong idea about how permissions and groups work. `john` will have all permissions `www-data` has, not the other way around....